Is 500mb of images possible to fit into an app for playstore and app-store policies?
I have two folders of images, combined they are 500mb. Is it possible to fit these as assets in my flutter app, without going above the limit for app size in google and app-store? I'm not really understanding the policies for it, it says that "individual asset pack" can go up to 1.5gb, does my 500mb of files count as asset packs?

I would prefer a link to download those images instead of increasing bundle size

Images count as an asset. You can easily fit 500mb of assets in you application and upload to playstore.
As per the playstore policy, you can add 1.5 GB of assets only.
so you are good to go.
